# How to do redirect via header in Opera?

Tags: php, redirect, header, opera

Hey, so i have been using this function in every project or page i work on.

```
function redirect_to($location = NULL) {
    if ($location != NULL) {
        header("Location: {$location}");
        exit;
    }
}
```

And now i checked Opera and that redirect don't work there? So this is very frustrating how should i fix it so it also works in Opera browser? 
Every other browser i have works perfectly: FF/IE/Chrome.

Also i might note that i do not have any output before that header and there is no spaces or free lines.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens in Opera? What does `$location` look like?

Comment: in opera it works too. It's your own skills to frustrate of.

Comment: Are you sure Opera browsers even reach this function? Do you have some user agent detection somewhere in your code?

Comment: @ Pekka - in the example i'm currently having problem i use $location = "../index.php"

Comment: @ stillstanding - Nop i don't have any kind of user agent detection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opera should work fine with header redirects.

As @stillstanding says, make 100% sure the line is reached in the first place. Do a test output of something else (`echo "test";`) and see whether that is visible.

According to specifications, header redirects require an **absolute** URL (even though clients usually support relative ones). Try whether this helps.

Comment: I tested
function redirect_to($location = NULL) {
 if ($location != NULL) {
  header('HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Permanently');
  header("Location: http://www.example.com/{$location}");
  echo $location;
  exit;
 }
}

And page in opera stops on logout.php page and displays echo statement index.php

Comment: If i open operas (firebug like tool) i see that response header there is set to Location: <code>http://www.example.com/index.php</code>

Comment: @arma that is mysterious. Can you confirm this on another machine?

Comment: @ Pekka - Not really i currently have this running on localserver. Well i'll need to delay this issue untill i bring this up on live server.

Comment: @arma you should confirm this elsewhere, it could be local to your Opera or crazy firewall / Antivirus package behaviour.

Comment: @ Pekka - sure i'll confirm this later when i put this online. I'll return here and update my issue status.

Comment: This was issue on my end not on code. When i updated to latest Opera version it was set to "disable automatic page redirections".
If anyone ever read this with same issue: "You can enable the automatic redirection in Preferences."

Thanks everybody for time spent.

Answer (score 1):

Just so that it helps others, in my case it was Opera refusing 2 redirects to same URL.

- Opera requests URL
- Some hidden PHP code adds cookie-checker-cookie and redirects to same URL
- Opera properly gets cookie and again requests original URL
- My code adds a cookie and redirects to same URL again
- Opera just stands there with blank page

Other browsers take a lot of redirects to same URL before quitting, but Opera stopped at 2nd redirect. Opera v12, that is.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to also set / send a HTTP redirection Status code; 301, 302 or 307.
See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3

Comment: In PHP if you issue a location header without specifying the status code it is automatically set to 302. You can specifically set the status code to be used by setting the third argument to header().

Comment: Mh, I’d try the other 2 status codes then. Maybe opera doesn’t like 302? I dunno …